# Change Layout of New Contact?

Tags: page-layout, contact, new

I am pretty new to Salesforce and am trying to set it up for my organization.

I am trying to change the "New" link for each of the entity types so that the layout the user sees is different from the standard, but I am not sure how to do so. I only have one entry under "Page Layouts" for the Object "Contact" and it looks like this controls what the user sees when they view a Contact, but what they are shown upon creation is different.

How can I change the "New Contact" layout?

Comment: You need to have different page ljayouts for your user and create record type. Search for both topics and their assignment to users, it quite easy and you would find a lot even in sfse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You need to decide if your user need standard page or customized visualforce page(If user need fields  other that fields in object). If they need Standard Layout, then create a new layout according to your requirement.
Second, If using VF page, then you need to override new button with that VF page.

Please follow the steps to create a page layout.

1. Go to Setup.
2. Search "Contact" . Under contact you will see page Layout. Click on page Layout
3. You will see a button on top("Page layout assignment").Click Edit on "Contact layout".
4. Drag the fields which you want to keep in page layout from fields panel and save.

Now click on page layout assignment button and assign the page layout to your profile.

Comment: Where do I create a new layout and how do I link it to the New button?

Comment: First tell u want to creating a page layout or vf page?

Comment: I don't really know the difference, but I think I just need a Standard Layout.

Comment: If you want I can assist you on skype by sharing screen

Comment: My connection isn't good enough, unforunately. Can you share the steps with how to edit the "New Contact" layout? I'd like to change the fields and the field order so that my org can enter the data the way we like to.

Comment: I think I just want to do a Standard Layout, by the way.

Comment: I will give steps in 5 mins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56726/discussion-between-muzammil-bajaria-and-skaz).

Comment: I was making these changes before but there was a delay so I didn't think it made the appropriate change, but it did.